# How to Generate Certificate Signing Request (CSR) format PCKS10 in iPhone?

Tags: ios, csr

1.Before requesting soft certificates from the CA, we need to build the PCKS10 data(CSR),and how to build in iPhone(use or do not use OpenSSL)?

2.When we get the certificate data,how to install it on the iPhone?

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277865/is-it-possible-to-generate-certificate-signing-request-csr-using-secuity-frame/21186714#21186714