# Is it possible to generate certificate signing request(.csr) using security framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, csr

I would like to make HTTPS request with a server require client-certificate authentication. I looked into this [Creating a SecCertificateRef for NSURLConnection Authentication Challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238559/creating-a-seccertificateref-for-nsurlconnection-authentication-challenge?rq=1). It worked as expected.

However, it needs to prepare the p12 file which includes the private key. It would be secured as it needs a password to import the p12 file using `SecPKCS12Import()`.

However, there could be other option. That is the iOS-client should make a certificate signing request(.CSR) and let a third party (the server) sign it.

For my search, I see that I can use `SecKeyGeneratePair()` for generating a key pair. But I don't see any API that generate a CSR.

Do I really need OpenSSL to achieve this?

Also, a bit off topic, once the iOS-client somehow receives the signed certificate. I can use `SecCertificateCreateWithData()` to retrieve an `SecCertificateRef()`. However, to fill in a `NSURLCredential`. I also need the `SecIdentityRef` which come from p12 file using `SecPKCS12Import()`. How can I retrieve a `SecIdentityRef` without `SecPKCS12Import()` but just a certificate file like `crt` or `der`?

Comment: I eventually build the `OpenSSL` to generate the CSR file. To get `SecIdentityRef` without p12 file, I look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241590/how-to-establish-a-secidentityref-in-an-iphone-keychain-without-a-p12)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no explicit support for CSR in Security Framework in iOS. However, it is not that difficult to build CSR 'manually' - it is just ASN.1 DER block of data that are available at iOS runtime.

Here is pseudo code of that:

1. Use `SecKeyGeneratePair()` from Security Framework to create fresh public/private key
2. Implement `getPublicKeyBits` method to retrieve NSData-form of fresh public key (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html )
3. Implement `getPrivateKey` method to retrieve SecKeyRef from Keychain
4. Follow http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2986.txt to construct ASN.1 DER of CSR in NSMutableData
5. Use CC_SHA1_* to create signature hash of Certification Request Info (part of CSR)
6. Use SecKeyRawSign and private key to sign CSR

This will create proper CSR (in form of NSData) that can be sent to CA for approval.

*My implementation is available on GitHub: http://github.com/ateska/ios-csr .*

Comment: I am very interested in seeing this class, no need to polish it. I have tried to generate a csr on iOS for 2 days now.

Comment: @ateska Do you know how you can save this as a proper file?

Comment: What do you mean by 'proper file' - you can just dump that NSData content to file - it will be CSR in DER format.

Comment: does anyone know which OID should I use to insert also the email address into the CSR ?

The one I used 1.2.840.113549.1.9.1 does not work.

Comment: @i-developer - an email is part of a subject, not a dedicated item of CSR (the most commonly).

Comment: @AlesTeska 
Can we create CSR with Elliptic Curve by using ecdsa-with-SHA256 ad you describe with RSA "https://github.com/ateska/ios-csr"(its quite helpful for me.), I've tried but its keep getting failed. Can you please help me on this how could I do this.

Comment: I tried and getting this PEM 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIG+MGkCAQAwSDERMA8GA1UEBgwIUGFraXN0YW4xETAPBgNVBAoMCEFzY2VydGlh
MQwwCgYDVQQLDANBU0MxEjAQBgNVBAMMCUQgU2lnbmluZzAYMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
AQUAAwcAMAQCAAIAoAAGCCqGSM49BAMCA0cAMEQCIHIifMMGs+r+lhN8id2ka5iJ
V/ieCtvinsYYGC8UohBjAiA9IkU0k+oUzTeYQnYxSDyPT1h2MRZUmQm/hz+0KjUk
Xg==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

Comment: @Aleem - well, my class is very 'RSA-centric'. You will need to adjust all RSA-specific parts to EC ones. Shouldn't be too difficult, I suggest to start with CSR generated by OpenSSL, identify differences using hex editor and adjust ASN.1 generator part accordingly.

Comment: @AlesTeska Could you please change the license for your library? That would help a lot (it's possibly illegal to distribute on [App Store with GPL-licensed software](http://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/more-about-the-app-store-gpl-enforcement)). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who comes across this in the future, I encountered [outfoxx's Shield library](https://github.com/outfoxx/Shield) which makes it super easy to create CSRs via Swift.