# iOS CSR generating with native tools

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ssl, csr

I want to generate CSR in iOS with native tools (not openssl). I searched, and I found that iOS doesn't have an API for that, so I began to search for third party libraries and I found [ateska's library](https://github.com/ateska/ios-csr) but I cannot use it, because it's GPL-2.0. licensed. Then I found [another library from outfoxx](https://github.com/outfoxx/Shield), (linked in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62293187/19893979) from Josh Correia) which is MIT licensed, so I could use it, but it's poorly documented, and I'm a newbie in iOS development, so I don't know how to generate the CSR with it. Could somebody please help me, and show an example how to use it? Thanks.

Comment: This would be more likely be answered if it was a comment on the post/answer originally mentioning the library rather than a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277865/is-it-possible-to-generate-certificate-signing-request-csr-using-security-fram/62293187#62293187

Comment: Yeah, I know, but unfortunately I'm so new to stackoverflow, that I can't make a comment yet :(

Comment: @Gabe Would you please link my question there?